# Memory Hierarchy Mappings to real world

Tags: cpu-cache, memory-hardware, os-kernel, cache

This article from IBM ([link](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/intro-to-lop/#:%7E:text=While%20operating%20systems%20present%20memory%20to%20the%20running%20applications%20as%20a%20unified%20space%2C%20modern%20large%20systems%20have%20memory%20organized%20in%20a%20hierarchy%2C%20by%20core%2C%20chip%2C%20module%2C%20socket%2C%20node%2C%20and%20chassis/central%20processor%20complex%20(CPC)%20for%20example.)) talks about Memory hierarchy in its actual hardware parts.

> NUMA
>
> While operating systems present memory to the running applications as a unified space, modern large systems have memory organized in a hierarchy, by core, chip, module, socket, node, and chassis/central processor complex (CPC) for example.

I suppose, just like

- core maps to *registers*,
- chip maps to *per-cpu cache*
- module maps to *shared cache*

What would others (socket, node and CHC) map to?

ps: By mapping, I mean that the registers are inside the cpu core (the hardare); per-cpu cache is present inside the chip (the hardware); shared-cache is present inside the module(the hardware)

Comment: Can you articulate a more concrete question?  I do not understand what you mean by "explains this mappings".  It probably is also helpful to tell us your thoughts, tell us what research you have done and what resources you have read, summarize what you have found so far to make the question useful for others, and ask a specific question.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74480487/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/155509/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: What do you mean by core maps to registers?  Can you give a definition of the mapping you have in mind?  A few examples are not a substitute for a general definition.

Comment: See this description as informal, there is no need for a one-to-one correspondence. The key idea is that the OS abstracts away all the complexity and structuring of the hardware, allowing much easier software development. Also keep in mind that the memory that a process sees is not necessarily just RAM, but a combination of RAM and disk.

Comment: this question makes no sense to me - especially "core maps to registers". What?

Comment: Article: "space is divided into many layers, such as room, apartment and dwelling." Question: "I suppose that room maps to doorknob, apartment maps to divided cellar space and building maps to shared cellar space. What do neighbourhood and city map to?"

Comment: By mapping, I meant that *registers* are inside cpu core (the hardare); per-cpu cache is present inside the chip (the hardware); shared-cache is present inside the module(the hardware)

Comment: I want to know; given, core, chip, module, socket, node, CHC; what memory is stored/present where.

Comment: If you mean by how a cpu is designed and where are different components located on a cpu die, then there is no general answer. It is an engineering task and specific to manufacturers, who keep updating their design. The article from IBM discusses about their system(organisation) which is not generalised(architecture).